# Spring AOP aspect doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gwt, aspectj

I'm using Spring+Hibernate+GWT for my app and it's work fine. I now want to catch exception with AOP because I use transaction and a simple try/catch block can't do the job. Here is my code in package  x.y.z.server.dao:

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateJpaDAO<K, E> {
protected Class<E> entityClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractHibernateJpaDAO() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass();
    entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

public void persist(E entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);

}
...   
private abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
}
```

my DAO inherits of this class like this :

```
@Repository("billOfLadingDAO")
public class BillOfLadingDAO extends
    AbstractHibernateJpaDAO<String, BillOfLading> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPUnit")
EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}
```

my service is implemented like this in package x.y.z.server.dao.daoserviceimpl

```
@Service("billOfLadingService")
public class BillOfLadingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    BillOfLadingService {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1282872068303829279L;

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory
        .getLog(BillOfLadingServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private BillOfLadingDAO billOfLadingDAO;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor =      MesExceptions.class)
public void save(BillOfLadingDTO billDTO) throws MesExceptions,Exception {

    try {
        if(billDTO.getUpdate()){
        billOfLadingDAO.merge(bill);
        }else {
        billOfLadingDAO.persist(bill);
        }

    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        LOG.error(e);
         throw new MesExceptions();
    }catch(Exception eb){
         throw new MesExceptions();
}
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z" />
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostPro     cessor" />

</beans>
```

I wrote my advide like this in order to catch dataaccessexception

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AfterThrowingIntercept {

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "within(x.y.z.server.dao..*)", throwing = "ex")
public void errorInterceptor(DataAccessException ex) throws Throwable {
    throw new MesExceptions();
}   
}
```

I call the save methode  billOfLadingService like this

```
billOfLadingService.save(bill, new AsyncCallback() {
...
});
```

Here are the complete stack trace:

```
2015-09-09 14:41:00,433 [qtp157780255-45] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'KJIOJIOOJ' for key 'PRIMARY' [n/a]
[INFO]com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'KJIOJIOOJ' for key 'PRIMARY'
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
[INFO]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2859)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPers ister.java:3300)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
[INFO]  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.save(Unknown Source)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:571)
[INFO]  at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:37)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But when I throw exception like duplicateentry my advice dosen't work. Can anyone help me?

NB: I want to throw my own exception because spring exception are not serializable and failed to be transfered by gwt rpc call.

Comment: I see 2 things 1. your packages don't match, 2. you aren't throwing anything as everything is caught and converted to a `MesException`. Another typ do't reinvent the generic JPA dao, use Spring Data JPA... Saves you writing a lot of code...

Comment: Thanks fo your reply. I have edited my post my packages match. It was a mistake. The code wich throws the exception is on the client side. The problem is that Dataasccessexception is thrown but my aspect doesn't catch it to convert it in     Mesexception.

Comment: And how should your server know about exceptions on the client?

Comment: What I mean is that on the client side I have a code which try to add a billoflading wich is already saved in the DB so a DuplicateKeyException is thrown. And I want to catch this exception and convert it in MesException.

Comment: With an aspect on the server.... How do you see that working. You are confusing me, you state an exception thrown on the client, but have an aspect for the server...

Comment: When I said  "on the client side I have a code which try to add a billoflading" it is just to specified that I use gwt so I do rpc call of a method wich is on the server from the client;  Of course the exception is thrown on the server side: On the client side I call the save methode like this

    billOfLadingService.save(bill, new AsyncCallback() {...});

Comment: But from the server there never will be an exception because you catch those...

Comment: Also WHERE are you throwing the exception? I see it no where and judging from your description you are throwing it yourself forcefully.

Comment: No as I said the try/catch block on the save didn't catch anything because of @Transactional annotation. So the commit is done after the methode execution. It is why I wanted to catch them with an aspect...

Comment: Yes I want to display a specific message when a user want to add a billoflading wich is already on the DB. So I'm throwing this exception and try to catch it...

Comment: Well actually that depends in this case on what is called. Persist will throw an exception immediately (as that issues the insert directly to know the id). The merge could be delayed depending on your flush mode. How many contexts do you have?

Comment: And again I'm asking WHERE are you throwing that exception...

Comment: I have edited my post with the stack trace got on the server

Comment: WHERE am i throwing that exception? I didn't catch very well, but I got the exception the I use the method billOfLadingService.save(bill, new AsyncCallback() {...}) where bill have the same id with another billoflading witch is already saved

Comment: You gave the impression you where throwing the exception yourself, hence my persistence. But the stack trace is showing that your advice isn't applied. Which makes me wonder is your Aspect detected by the component-scan? Also your point cut should be `within` not `Within`...

Comment: Ok also a mistake I had already change Within to within. And Yes my aspect is detected because  when it was Within I got an error and  I change it to within and it works fine.

Comment: Instead of `within` try `execution(* x.y.z.server.dao..*.*(..))`... You also might want to enable trace or debug logging for `org.springframework.aop` to see what is actually being done.

Comment: And specify the `order` attribute for `<aop:aspectj-auto-proxy >` and `<tx:annotation-driven />` and make sure that Aspectj kicks in before the transactional interceptor.

Comment: I have already tried this... But When I remove @Transactional it works fine the prolem is with transaction I think...

Comment: Hence the suggestion to change the ordering of aspects and the use of an `execution` point cut instead...

Comment: ok but which order should I use I don't know a lot about that it is my first project with spring and hibernate

Comment: Doesn't really matter as long as the aspectj comes before the transactional.

Comment: ok thank you so much it works fine...